# PowrBI BCI_Calendar

Tags: powerbi

I'm working with a date's from my DB using BCI Calendar it's working fine but unable to read the data is anyone knows what is the issue [image]

Comment: what do you mean by - "unable to read the data"?

Comment: Seems like all numbers for the 17th get stacked on each other. Please explain what you have done in the background so we understand how you came to this result

Comment: Just add two columns from my DB 
1 For the date of order (Start Date and End Date)
2 Count the number of Order 
The values are stack on each other its a count of my sales orders